# How to only get a list of the Folders of an existing OneDrive folder c#

Tags: c#, filter, onedrive

I'm starting to play around with the OneDrive API for .net, in order to get a list of all the items included within a folder i'm using the following call:

```
Item folder=null;
        try
        {
            string expandValue = "thumbnails,children";

            folder = await  a_oneDriveDevice.Drive.Root.ItemWithPath(path) 
                            .Request()
                            .Expand(expandValue)
                            .GetAsync();

        }
        catch (Exception ohno)
        {

        }
```

However i have been unable to find within the documentation what are the proper filters to add to the Expand() function to retrieve only a list of files (or folders). 
Could anybody point me to the right direction?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want the filter to apply to the children of the item you're requesting, you're correct that you will need to update the `expandValue`. Since the API is built around OData, your filter will actually become a sub-option on the children expansion, so something like this is what you're after:

```cs
string expandValue = "thumbnails,children(filter=folder%20ne%20null)";
```

Comment: Also, expanding thumbnails on a request for a folder will only provide thumbnails for that folder. If you want to get thumbnails for the children of a folder, I recommend doing this request instead: `Drive.Root.ItemWithPath(path).Children.Request().Expand("thumbnails").Filter("folder ne null").GetAsync()`